# Avoiding exceptions when uploading files in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a file upload field (attachment1) in a form that may or may not have a file uploaded in it when I process the form in laravel.

When I'm trying to process the page, this line generates an exception:

```
Input::upload('attachment1',path('storage').'attachments/'.$name);
```

Here is the text of the exception:

```
Message:
Call to a member function move() on a non-object
```

it seems that I need to check in advance to see if `'attachment1'` has a file, and I found that the function `Input::has_file('attachment1')` is supposed to tell me whether or not `'attachment1'` has a file, but even when I submit an empty form, it returns true.

Also, from reading documentation, it seems that `Input::upload` is supposed to just return false when trying to upload a non-existant file, so why does it produce this exception instead, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `$_FILES` will have the `tmp_name` key in it regardless of whether a file is uploaded or not. It's sent as an empty string though, not `NULL`. It appears `has_file()` expects `NULL`:

```
public static function has_file($key)
{
    return ! is_null(static::file("{$key}.tmp_name"));
}
```

To work around it in your controller you could try:

```
if (array_get(Input::file('attachment1'), 'tmp_name'))
{
    // file uploaded
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try to do some checking before trying to upload the attachment.
This works for me:

```
$file = Input::file('attachment1');
 if (is_array($file) && isset($file['error']) && $file['error'] == 0) {
 Input::upload('attachment1',path('storage').'attachments/'.$name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to figure out how Laravel works with uplaod and files, i learned some points. I hope they will be helpful to you

First:

> "Message: Call to a member function move() on a non-object"

This exception may be thrown because your folder may not have write permissions.

Second:

You can validate your input in your validation rules like

> 'attachment' => 'image|mime:jpg,gif,png|max:(in kilobytes)

Third:

I am using bootstrap extended in my project. They prefer not to use "name" attr. with

```
<input type="file" />
```

You may check it out from this [link](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) Please scroll down to the options section and read the description column of name. Thus i understood basically,  Laravel returns true even if input is empty because actually it is part of post

Fourth: I would like to share my code and accept any recommendations. I hope they all help...

```
try
    {

        $comp = new Company();
        $comp->name = newCompanyForm::get('name');
        $comp->save();
        if($comp)
        {
                if(newCompanyForm::has('logo'))
                {

                    $logo = Input::upload('logo', path('public').'company_logos');
                    if($logo)
                    {

                        $comp->logo = URL::base().'lms/company_logos/'.$logo->getfileName();
                        $comp->save();
                    }
                    else
                        throw new \Exception("Logo yüklenirken hata oluştu. Şirket logosuz kayıt edildi.");
                }
                Session::flash('status_success', 'Şirket eklendi.');
                newCompanyForm::forget_input();
                return Redirect::back();
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("Şirket eklenirken hata oluştu. Şirket eklenmedi.");

    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        $errors->add('lms', $e->getMessage());
        return Redirect::back()->with_errors($errors);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest 'Laravel' way to do this would be to check for the input name.

```
if (Input::has('attachment1'))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```